# Measuring acceleration in g's

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am using adxl335 accelerometer with Arduino uno r3 to measure acceleration due to gravity along x axis. I am using 50 ms delay and printing to serial. 
I have two questions, which are;

- Can I measure fractional values, like .8 in acceleration due to gravity?
- when I shake the accelerometer up down along x axis, I don't see any variations in 'g'?

I am using analog pins and 3.3V power supply from Arduino to power the sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL335.pdf) you can quickly find that the output of the device is 300mV per *g*.  That means:

1. Read the analog value
2. Convert it to millivolts
3. Divide it by 300

The result is the *g* value.  If you do it using floating point then yes, you get fractions of a *g* resolution.

For instance:

```
float mv = analogRead(0) / 1023.0 * 5000.0; 
float g = mv / 300.0;
```

If the analog channel has 1024 steps, that's 5/1024 = 0.0048828V per step, or 4.8828mV per step.  Divide that by 300 and you get a resolution of 0.01628g

As for not seeing variations in X when you shake up and down, maybe that is because you really want to look at the Z axis, not the X. X is left/right, Y is forward/backward and Z is up/down.  It's all in the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL335.pdf) - it makes for good reading, I suggest you take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I looked at the data sheet but it turned out to be that I was directly dividing the analogRead by 300. As for the variation in g it turns out that I wasn't shaking too hard and the code was wrong. Thanks again